# Force application to load DLL last

Tags: windows, assembly, dll, hook

I have a DLL that hooks into various functions of an application's DLLs, but it's not certain that the DLL gets loaded last, creating a chance that the application crashes at startup because the DLL tried to put the hooks in unallocated memory.

Is it possible to force the application to load the DLL last, or for the DLL to  force itself to be loaded last?  What is the best (cleanest/fastest) way to do this?

*Note: I programmed this DLL in assembly, but any solution that involves C code is fine too (if it'll even involve actual code).*

**SOLUTION:** I injected LoadLibrary in the main() with a debugger, and put the name of the DLL at the end of the application with a hex editor, now it works :) thanks

Comment: Give your DLL a load-time dependency on each of the DLLs it hooks?

Comment: The DLL holds functions I have rewritten from the application and it's other DLLs, I change the jump table of the DLLs and the application so it jumps to my own "hooked" functions.

-When the other DLLs aren't loaded, their jump table isn't there yet either, so my DLL will try to change an unexisting jump table.

Comment: Make it [Delay-Loaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9zd12s.aspx). Or yes, call `LoadLibrary` in your `main` function (after dynamically loading other _dll_ s - if any), when all the _dll_ s that the app was linked against are already loaded (unless they are Delay-Loaded).